# Можно ли с помощью Telegram-бота отправлять zip файлы?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, zip, telebot

Нужно с помощью Telegram-бота отправлять zip файлы.

Есть ли такая возможность и если да то буду благодарен за ссылку на ресурс с ответом на этот вопрос(я искал, но не нашел(может плохо искал)). За функцию буду благодарен вдвойне.

P.S.

Язык - Python

Библиотека - pyTelegramBotApi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55470047

Answer (score 2):

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
with open('path/to/file', 'rb') as file:
    bot.send_document(chat_id, file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю есть функция `bot.send_document(message.chat.id, имя_файла)`

Пример использования:

```
import telebot
bot=telebot.Telebot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler
def send_zip(message):
 if message.text="Send me zip!":
  send.document(message.chat.id,"file.zip")
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```